# How to implement notification functionality?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, observer-pattern

I know the question is so vague that it explains no details. Apologies for that. Now, as the title suggests I want to implement a notification functionality.

To be more specific, I want to build a React + Spring Boot application in which React will use Spring Boot based REST API to get, post information, and so on. (If there's a better way of doing this, please do not hesitate to suggest)

Now, back to functionality. Assume, there're newspapers and subscribers. If a newspaper that subscriber has subscribed adds news, I want the subscriber to be notified.(Observer pattern?)

One way and the most common way of solving it (as far as I have seen from Google search results) is to set some sort of interval and hitting the REST API, say in every 5 seconds. But I do believe and I am sure that it is not  efficient. Even if my application is just a demo in which I'm trying to learn different stuffs.

To wrap up, I ask you a way, slightly more detailed method of implementation, if possible. As I mentioned, I know it is Observer pattern, but how can I implement it in the setup I have mentioned?

Thanks, in advance and sorry for any unintended mistakes I have made while describing the problem.

Comment: Why would timed fetching be not efficient? That's completely normal of implementing notifications. Be sure to cache the results and not recalculate the same thing every time since they are similar to all the subscribers. Alternative for you would be sockets, but that's only in case you need real time changes

Comment: Wouldn't that cause some sort of overhead? I'm asking it out of curiosity.
Also, as I mentioned, how about Observer Pattern? How that can be implemented?

Comment: Observer Pattern or whatever else magic you are trying to use is all done on backend side. Once calculated you have to notify the clients that changes have been made via a socket. Am I not understanding what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Understood, thanks for the response.

Comment: As far as I know there are 3 ways of achieving what you need: request pooling (send a request on a time interval), server sent events (spring actually has a pretty good support for this), and websockets (only go for this if you need real time, if you don't it's not worth the trouble)

Comment: @SrThompson, could you please give me more details about the second one?

Comment: @MensurQulami a server sent event is basically the opposite of an HTTP request, you subscribe to the event from your frontend and when the server fires it you get something back. I never implemented it myself, but the information is there on the internet. It's not particularly difficult to get something basic running

Comment: Thank You :) @SrThompson